# BasicHTTPServer, SimpleHTTPServer and concurrency

Tags: python, concurrency, simplehttpserver

I'm writing a small web server for testing purposes using python, BasicHTTPServer and SimpleHTTPServer. It looks like it's processing one request at a time. Is there any way to make it a little faster without messing around too deeply?
Basicly my code looks as the following and I'd like to keep it this simple ;)

```
os.chdir(webroot)
httpd = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer(("", port), SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
print("Serving directory %s on port %i" %(webroot, port) )
try:
 httpd.serve_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
 print("Server stopped.")
```

Comment: why dont you use twisted for creating a HTTPServer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can make your own threading or forking class with a mixin inheritance from [SocketServer](http://docs.python.org/library/socketserver.html):

```
import SocketServer
import BaseHTTPServer

class ThreadingHTTPServer(SocketServer.ThreadingMixIn, BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer):
    pass
```

This has its limits as it doesn't use a thread pool, is limited by the GIT, etc, but it could help a little (with relatively little effort).  Remember that requests will be served simultaneously by multiple threads, so be sure to put proper locking around accesses to global/shared data (unless such data's immutable after startup) done in the course of serving a request.

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398144/python-basehttpserver-httpserver-concurrency-threading) covers the same ground (not particularly at length).

Comment: Sadly I'm stuck on 16 requests per second - with 1 concurrent request as well as with 10.

Comment: @braindump, if you're on any form of Unix (basically anything except Windows), try a ForkingMixin instead of the ThreadingMixin, it might serve you better, esp. if you're on a multicore CPU.  Otherwise, you'll really need to move to some kind of "real" server (Tornado, for example: see http://www.tornadoweb.org/ -- simple, and very high performance per http://bret.appspot.com/entry/tornado-web-server ).

Comment: I'm on Gentoo Linux on an ARM-based CPU. Thanks for your hint regarding Forking, it's much better now, even if it's not good ;)
But for my intention, it's okay. (On 10 concurrent requests, I got 60 requests per second. Lighttpd reaches ~400 requests per second on the same machine)

Comment: @braindump, lighttpd's based on an async approach, I believe, just like Tornado, which I recommended.  But if 60 QPS are OK for your purposes, there's no real need for you to check if Tornado would reach 300, 400, or whatever;-).

Comment: Thank for useful tip! A tiny import/typo fixup, should be "from SocketServer import ThreadingMixIn" (not imported as submodule otherwise, at least under python 2.6) and later use "ThreadingMixIn" (also note the capital 'I' in MixIn).

Answer (score 1):

You might also look at [CherryPy](http://cherrypy.org) -- it's pretty simple, too, and has multiple request threads with no additional effort.  Although your needs may be modest now, CP has a lot of nice capabilities that may benefit you in the future.

Comment: Are you sure about concurrency? I can't find it in their documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what your requirements are, another option might be to hook in [Paste](http://pythonpaste.org/do-it-yourself-framework.html). Though, based on your example, it may be overkill.  Something to keep in the toolbox.